# Vite and RTLCSS

Tags: vue.js, vite, postcss, rtlcss

I'm using vite and vue 3 for compile my less file and using my less in index.html file like blow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/less/default.less">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i want to my less file also compile to [RTLCSS](https://rtlcss.com/index.html) so when i change the default.less to default-rtl.less, vite use my rtl.less file (in dev mode) and when i build my project it render two separated file like *.css and *-rtl.css
i have no ide how can i do it!